# Does the Wrap function in ColdFusion insert CR/LFs?

Tags: coldfusion, word-wrap

I have the need to do some word wrapping with a few considerations:

1. Source file is MS WORD
2. Copy and paste the text into a textarea in a cfform.
3. Use

   ```
   #wrap(theTextVar,80)#
   ```

   to dump out the text 80 characters
4. The text is uploaded to a legacy system which needs ansi or ascii chars uploaded.

Everything seems to work okay, I just wanted to confirm see if anyone else has had luck doing this and if they know if a CR / LF is entered after each line in the outputted text (Step 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on wrap():

> Uses the operating-system specific
>   line break: newline for UNIX, carriage
>   return and newline on Windows.

So if you are doing this on a Windows box, then the answer is yes.

Comment: My Dev machine is OS X, but the production will be windows..  I must have missed the snippet above, thanks for pointing it out!

Here's the cf 9 reference
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7114.html

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
<cffile action="write" file="i_will_show_the_secret_if_you_open_me_in_text_editor.html" output="#wrap(theTextVar,80)#" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that would do the same thing.  I was concerned with what Ben Doom pointed out.  Appreciate your reply!